# How to reverse obfuscation in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

Is obfuscation only about garbling the names of non-public variables/members? If so, would it not be possible to write an application that would at least change these names more readible ones like "variable1", etc, and then extract the whole code that can still be compiled?

Comment: Of course its possible. Usually its called reverse engineering/deassemble/decompile etc (if you are looking for a tool).

Comment: For an example of such a tool, see http://de4dot.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is about a lot more, especially with more sophisticated obfuscators. They can produce IL that **cannot** be expressed in most languages, and where the logic flow is horribly tangled to befuddle the best of tools. With **lots of time** you can do it (probably lots by hand), and there is certainly an arms race between the obfuscators and deobfuscators - but you vastly underestimate the technology here.

Also, note that many obfuscators look at an entire application (not just one assembly), so they can change the public API too.

Comment: This sounds cool, do you have a link for this? Sounds completely rad!

Comment: @stefan check out http://brajeshmahor.blogspot.com/2010/11/code-security-net-obfuscation.html

Comment: @BrokenGlass that does nothing that Marc Gravell wrote about. And iam not assuming you can get 1:1 code back, but a compileable and easy to analyze code piece.

Comment: Thanks, but how can obfuscators change so much without breaking the app or changing the behaviour or slow down the performance, etc? Also I thought they aren't allowed to change the public APIs. I guess that's an option the original developer can use if he knows there is no public API intended?

Comment: @Joan - you can usually tell it explicitly to ignore particular types, but in general at the **application** level there *is* no public API; but if you are obfuscating a **library**, then yes - it has to preserve that. Re slow-down; not really - the CLI doesn't care if the IL is spaghetti.

Comment: @Marc Gravell Again, can I see some links? For your original post and about that the CLI (speed wise) doesn't care if the IL is spaghetti?

Comment: @stafan - just read [any](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/obfuscation/features) [features](http://www.secureteam.net/Obfuscator.aspx) [page](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/compare-editions) [available](http://www.remotesoft.com/salamander/obfuscator.html) - spaghatti === control flow obfuscation. Re CIL caring - why would it? In fact, I write on-the-fly IL for a tool I maintain, and tools like reflector can't cope with *that* simply due to some the IL constructs you can use... IL is bizarre but powerful.

Comment: @Marc Gravell control obfuscation can probably brake shit loads of optimizations in a JIT, why would it NOT? Youre links are still not on topic.

Comment: @stefan maybe some; I wouldn't expect much harm here re JIT, to be honest. The links are *certainly* on-topic re the *post* - I take it you are focusing on the performance query? In that scenario - YMMV, measure in your local scenario, etc ;)  But at this point, especially with string encryption etc - you are largely saying "what matters most here is the IP privacy"

Comment: @Marc Gravell string encryptions etc are not a matter for me. Iam only thinking about the code flow, and yes I strongly believe the penalties speed wise will vary alot depending where and how you obfuscate. After all theres a reason why we want global optimizations :)

Comment: @Marc, what do you mean when you said "tools like reflector can't cope with that"? It can't show the code? Also if scripts are encrypted like you said, then those are gonna be decrypted which will cost more time and also be incompatible with string interning and all that stuff the C# compiler does it for you?

Comment: @Joan indeed - reflector can show the il, but not decompile to any language; it isn't obfuscated per se; is just uses IL tricks that you can't write in code. Fully obfuscated code usually struggles to load at all into reflector. re interning; that isn't a compiler feature, but a JIT/CLI on the ldstr opcode, but indeed: it may perform differently. My understanding is that the obfuscators work hard to minimise negative effects of this.

Comment: @Marc: Thanks, if you manage to do that, then isn't your method sort of a step ahead of obfuscators? Because obfuscated code still seems to have a structure but reading IL code seems much less intuitive. Also if you don't mind me asking, why did you do this? Just to fool the reflector and reverse compiling?

Comment: @Joan - my reasons have nothing to do with obfuscation; it is some OSS serialization code that uses meta-programming to write the most appropriate serialization code at runtime, which can be quite... gnarly. Simply, at points in that the most appropriate IL *happens* to be stuff that makes no sense in terms of languages.

Comment: @Marc Gravell could you possible add some of those obfuscators that you list as the best ones I am curious to see some of the names.

Answer (score 2):

That is certainly the *start* of an obfuscator. Though some obfuscators will also encrypt strings and other such tricks to make it *very* difficult to reverse engineer the assembly.

Of course, since the runtime needs to run the assembly after all of this, it is possible for a determined hacker to reverse engineer it :)

Answer (score 2):

There are '*deobfuscator*' tools to undo several obfuscation techniques like Decrypt strings, Remove proxy methods, Devirtualize virtualized code, Remove anti-debug code, Remove junk classes, Restore the types of method parameters and fields and more...

One very powerful tool is [de4dot](https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot).

But there are [more](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:.NET_Deobfuscation_Tools).

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscation is about changing meaningful names like `accountBalance` to meaningless ones like `a1`.
The application will obviously still work, but it will be more difficult to understand the algorithms inside it.

Comment: That is one (stupid) way of obfuscation yup. Imagine being high on LSD and still making the stuff work. Thats a good obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

It's depend upon the obfuscation technology used. Obsfucating variable name is only one part of the issue. A lot of obfuscation tools perform some kind of program flow obfuscation at the same time, which will complicate further code comprehension. At the end, the obfuscated IL won't be expressible easily (if at all) in most programming languages.

Renaming the variables and fields won't help you much either, as having a lot of variable1, variable2.. won't help you to understand what you read.